# Jest - test returns "serializes to the same string"

Tags: jestjs

I have this test:

```
describe('reminderEventLoopDateAfter', () => {
    test('returns start of the day, of a date 1 month in the future', () => {
        const testDate = date.reminderEventLoopDateAfter('2022-01-01T20:00:00+0500', 1, 'months');
        expect(testDate).toEqual('2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z');
    });
});
```

where `reminderEventLoopDateAfter` is:

```
const reminderEventLoopDateAfter = (now, days = 0, unit = 'day') => dayjs(now).utc().add(days, unit).startOf('day');
```

Why do i get this being thrown by the test?

```
Expected: "2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
Received: serializes to the same string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jest is telling you that the `testDate` when printed to console is `2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z`. And if Jest were to print out(serialize `testDate`)

```
Expected: "2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
Received: "2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
```

as the test result, that would be confusing, since the test fails because the actual `testDate` is a `Day.js` object, which is not equal to the string "2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z". You probably intended to either convert the "2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z" to a `Day.js` object or convert your `testDate` to a string before doing the assertion with them.

Answer (score 1):

The `testDate` object is not a string, it's an object. It happens to resolve to the string but they are not equal, so using `toEqual` fails to compare identically. You can change your test to this and it should work:

```js
expect(testDate.format()).toEqual('2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z');
```

Since the `format()` function returns a string it will allow the comparison you want.